# Captivate: Add a playbar to an in-slide video

Tags: video, adobe-captivate

I have a video in my slide which plays when the user enters the slide.
I need to know how I can add a playbar to this video so the user can pause the video when he wants to.

Thanks

(adobe captivate 6)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for your issue, but try inserting the video straight to the stage vs pulling it from the library. ![insert video][1] For some reason when you do this you get the playbar at the bottom of the screen. I have noticed that when this is added your image becomes distorted to compensate for adding the bar.